# please help me with the function mail() to send yhe content of a form to my mail

Tags: php, forms, email

I'm trying to send the content of a form directly to my mail, but when I use the function mail() i get:

( ! ) Warning: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in C:\wamp64\www\projects\monsite\contact.php on line 9

how to resolve please?

Comment: Do you have a smtp server running on localhost and port 25?

Comment: I dont't know what is this, I'm beginner, I use Wamp for windows as a localhost